# How to read data with two columns for y (dependent)?

Tags: regression, self-study, sas

I'm trying to fit a nonlinear model for the first time, so this might be a very dumb question. I have a simple data set: 1 column of x variable but for the dependent variable there are two numbers in the y column for each x observation.

How should I read this into SAS (or interpret it in words)?

Comment: How would we know how to interpret this if you don't? Your question is lacking detail necessary to answer your question.  Can you post a sample of what your dataset looks like and describe in more detail what you are trying to do?

Comment: the text book question gives no context for the problem. it gives me a model to fit the data to and then the data set. heres my attempt at giving a sample: (for row 1) x= 1 y= 2,3. Wish I had more info to give

Comment: Please add the self-study tag to this question as well since this is a homework/textbook question.

Comment: Is it possible the comma is being used as a decimal separator? In continental Europe (and some other places) 2,3 means 2.3

Comment: @Silverfish, excellent point.  I hadn't considered that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your additional comments, it appears that the x-value is fixed at X=1.  So there are two observations at that fixed level of x (for the first row).  One observation has a $y$ value of 2 and the other a $y$ value of 3.  So, the first row would be read in as two separate observations:

```
x     y
--------------
1     2
1     3
.     .
.     .
.     .
```

You could enter the first row into SAS with:

```
data mydata;
input x y;
cards;
1 2
1 2
;
run;
```

There is no interpretation to give until after you have fit the model.

Comment: Ksims: Your data is in "wide form" and you need to convert it to "long form". I haven't used SAS, but perhaps you could find som info here: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/widetolong_data.htm